Android Studio & kotlin with layouts-How to get an ant.png moving around the screen, all without going off screen
I am currently learning and having some issues in regards to an app i'm making.
The app will be for me about learning how to draw objects on the canvas and to get these ant.png's moving around freely, wandering in a natural way like a real ant, ive tried a number of ways however due to my learning and abilities i might not be adding the code exactly where it might need to go or even correctly.
As you can see from the code below, i more than likely need help with the way i have used it and where and why ive laid it out this way.
any help or explanations as to what and why i'm going wrong is greatly appreciated.
Thank You
mark117h.
MainActivity.kt.
package com.example.antnaturalmovement

import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.SurfaceHolder
import android.view.SurfaceView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.cancel
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.isActive
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    
    private lateinit var surfaceView: SurfaceView
    private lateinit var ant: Ant
    private var antDrawingJob: Job? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        // Initialize the SurfaceView and Ant class
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView)
        ant = Ant(this)
        
        // Add the callback for the SurfaceHolder
        surfaceView.holder.addCallback(this)
    }
    
    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        // When the surface is created, start the coroutine to draw the ant
        antDrawingJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            while (isActive) {
                drawAnt()
                delay(30) // Adjust the delay to control the update frequency
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
        // Handle surface changes if needed
    }
    
    override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        // Cancel the drawing coroutine when the surface is destroyed
        antDrawingJob?.cancel()
    }
    
    private fun drawAnt() {
        val canvas: Canvas? = surfaceView.holder.lockCanvas()
        if (canvas != null) {
            // Clear the canvas with a specific background color (e.g., white)
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
            
            // Update the ant's position
            ant.updatePosition(surfaceView.width, surfaceView.height)
            
            // Draw the ant at the updated position
            ant.draw(canvas)
            
            // Unlock the canvas and post the drawing
            surfaceView.holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
        }
    }
}

Ant.kt.
package com.example.antnaturalmovement

import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.cancel
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.isActive
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.random.Random
class Ant(context: Context) {
    private val antBitmap: Bitmap
    private val paint: Paint = Paint()
    var x: Float = 100f // Initial x position
    var y: Float = 100f // Initial y position
    private var direction: Float = Random.nextFloat() * 360 // Initial direction in degrees
    private var speed: Float = 5f // Speed in pixels per frame
    
    init {
        // Load the ant.png image from the drawable resources
        val originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ant)
        
        // Scale the image to 120 pixels by 120 pixels
        val width = 120
        val height = 120
        antBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, width, height, true)
    }
    
    fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        // Draw the scaled ant bitmap at the current (x, y) position on the canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(antBitmap, x, y, paint)
    }
    
    fun updatePosition(screenWidth: Int, screenHeight: Int) {
        // Convert direction to radians for trigonometric functions
        val radians = Math.toRadians(direction.toDouble())
        
        // Update position
        x += (cos(radians) * speed).toFloat()
        y += (sin(radians) * speed).toFloat()
        
        // Check for collision with the screen edges and reverse direction if needed
        if (x <= 0 || x + antBitmap.width >= screenWidth) {
            direction = 180 - direction
        }
        if (y <= 0 || y + antBitmap.height >= screenHeight) {
            direction = -direction
        }
        
        // Randomly change direction at intervals
        if (Random.nextInt(100) < 5) { // 5% chance to change direction
            direction += Random.nextFloat() * 60 - 30 // Change direction by -30 to 30 degrees
        }
        
        // Ensure direction stays within 0 to 360 degrees
        if (direction < 0) direction += 360
        if (direction >= 360) direction -= 360
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>


In response to my own queries above, i have concentrated my time and energy on getting the Ant.kt class working and moving correctly and being as clean and errors free as i can get, i am nearly there now though so i will post the updated code here for anyone wanting information on moving .png's around the screen and not going off screen, still needs work on the rotation though and getting it to rotate and then move in direction its rotated to.
